# Zurb Foundation Orbit Slider Pause on 3rd Slide

Tags: javascript, zurb-foundation, orbit

I added animation speeds, and can pause on hover; however, I was curious if with JS I am able to pause on a certain slide, or at least a certain time. Any suggestions how this might be possible?

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The orbit js dispatches events when the slide changes 'orbit.next' 'orbit.prev'...

```
  //from the orbit js
  this.$element.bind('orbit.next', function () {
    self.shift('next');
  });

  this.$element.bind('orbit.prev', function () {
    self.shift('prev');
  });
```

you can listen to these events with jQuery, eg.

```
$("#featured").bind('orbit.next orbit.prev', function(event){
      console.log('slide change', event);
  });
```

Not sure how you would get the time, but you could alter the orbit js to expose the info you need.

To get the slide number you could enable the 'slideNumber' option

```
slideNumber: true,               // display slide numbers?
```

and get the number from the display.

Hope this helps.